# How to trigger click on ref in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list

```
<li v-for="menu_item, key in menu" @click="clickMenu(key)" :ref="'menu'+key">
  {{menu_item.name}}
</li>
```

And in my vue I have

```
mounted(){
   // This shows the $refs as being mounted and available
   console.log(this.$refs)
   console.log(this.$refs.menu1)
   // Click menu item 2 seconds after mounting
   this.$refs.menu1.click()
   // click is UNDEFINED

},
methods: {
   clickMenu:function(key){
      console.log("CLICKED "+key)
   },
}
```

I get "Cannot read property 'click' of undefined"

How do I simply just trigger a click on the element programmatically?

Another answer on Github says I should do ...

```
 this.$refs.menu1.$el.click()
```

But that isn't defined either ??

Heres a JSFiddle
Hopefully someone can figure it out
[JSFIDDLE HERE!!](https://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/Lr2eptaw/3/)

Comment: Yes, Im aware I can get the element with javascript and do it that way.  I wanted to know if its possible, through Vue $refs.  Because Ive seen previous SO questions say that the above is how you do it.....but....its not apparently

Comment: What is the `this` reference inside the `setTimeout` context? Is it actually holding a reference to your Vue context?

Comment: @jdmcnair  ignore that, its not important, cuz it was just for illustration purpostes. 
 I have the actual method to trigger, seperate.  Ive updated a JSFiddle to look at. to see what I mean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may a couple of small issues with your code. The context of `this` inside `setTimeout()` when using `function() {}` is not what you are expecting. To preserve the context of `this` to be able to access `$refs` and similar component properties/functions, use an arrow function instead `() => {}`.

The next issue is accessing the underlying element of a ref such as `menu1`. I've provided an example below, but logging `this.$refs.menu1` returns an array of elements `[<li>]`. You would need to do something along the lines of `this.$refs.menu1[0]` to access the underlying element (there be a more "Vue" way of doing this though):

```
{
  // ...
  methods: {
    handleClick(key) {
      console.log(key);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs);
    console.log(this.$refs.menu1[0]);
    console.log(this);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this);
        this.$refs.menu1[0].click();
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/1k0fehaL/1/) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thank you!!  The settimeout thing wasnt really important, since I just used it for the example (and didnt notice the self/this mistake). In my real code Im using a method to trigger the click anyways....But.....accessing the element with [0].  That was the money!! :)  Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear it helped. That being said, there may be a more "Vue" way to do, some specific `$` prefixed property so be on the lookout in case other answers pop up.

Comment: Yeah.  I like this way though, because Im using a jQuery scroll/menu library outside of Vue.  So I need to trigger a click on the actual DOM element.  Obviously its a hack, and I should find some Vue meny/scrolly thing alternative, but for now this works lol

Answer (score -1):

if your goal is to click on the first item of menu, just call the clickMenu method and send the index, for this case it would be clickMenu(0).

Comment: I need to trigger a click programmatically on the actual DOM element.  Because Im using an external jQuery library unfortunately